# Trouble locking an object to an axis while moving them!

Tags: transforms

Using either the G-- x,y,z or even the gimbal, the object seems to jump out of alignment along one of the other axis.

For example, trying out Blender Guru tutorials, trying to move a circle vertically down, I would press G, then the axis to lock... but the circle seems to "jump off the rails" so to speak... and seems to come closer to me.

Even in a pure side view where it appears to only move vertically, soon as you swing into a 3d view... it has mysteriously moved out of the axis I was trying to move it along.

I'm not using the move excluding a certain axis, and I've played with the various orientation controls in the move menu.. I'm stumped.. and unable to move any precisely!

Comment: you say that the object jumps, which looks like you've enabled the snap option, then what you say doesn't fit that explanation... maybe share your file? (keep only one object) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: OMG I'M A CERTIFIABLE IDIOT! Thank you SO much!! I knew it had to be something simple!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable the [*Snap*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) option. Right now it must be set to *Increment*, which means that the object will snap to the 3D view grid.

[image]

Comment: This is rather a comment.

Comment: what do you mean? Actually this is the solution he was looking for...

Comment: @Lukasz I added a manual link. Would you care to explain why this doesn't answer the question and what would be needed to answer the question?

Comment: @Leander, moonbots: this is a **one-liner** and I'm officialy told to avoid them every time I write them which is a rarity. Second It's a one-liner with a link, which is not welcomed here as far as I know.

Comment: Only a single user can be notified with @ - comments. I have read [the help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/answering) and failed to find anything about "one-liners", only the statement *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.* . Even if the link goes down, the information is still there and OP can look up "Snap" by theirself. I think this does not have the negative aspects of a [link-only](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link) answer. Either way, I would be happy if you added some info with an edit.

Comment: Lukasz-40sth, I first answered him with a simple comment, that's why I didn't feel the need to make a complete answer   ;)   but you were right, I've completed